# Cannot Launch Instant App From Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

Cannot launch instant app from android studio. I did everything from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#kotlin) correctly. I uninstalled app from device. I also tried using with command `ia run` but it gives error `bash: ia: command not found`. Google play instant development SDK is 1.9.0. No error was given.

Comment: Can you upload the error logs, information is insufficient.

Comment: No error was given.

Comment: Did you change the manifest and gradle? Also try to clear your cache from android studio. Does your emulator contain google play store? If running on physical device you need to enable the instant app option on google play.

Comment: Yes I changed manifest and gradle. Cleared cache from android studio. Yes contains play store. Enabled  instant app.

Comment: Hmm thats quite weird, did you check if the permissions you enabled are supported for instant app? Also, did you check whether your code works on other devices?

Comment: Yes, it's supported for instant app. It doesn't work on the other device either.

Comment: Hmm without your code its hard to determine what other errors you could be facing. The questions I asked you above were some common errors I faced while setting up instant apps.

Comment: By the way, when you said there is no error, did you only check the build or did you also check the logcat?

Comment: Also on logcat there is no error related to instant app.

Answer (score 0):

The error "command not found" means that the executable file (in this case: "ia") isn't found in your OS search path settings, nor your current working directory. You'll need to either change your current directory to the Instant Dev SDK's installation directory, or set add the location to your environment's search paths.

The default path should be:
${path/to/android/sdk/}extras/google/instantapps